# What is happening to my Chilli plants?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, peppers, chili

My new Chilli plant leaves are having light and dark pigmentation with shriveled leaves. How can I fix this? [image]

[image]

Comment: What are your growing conditions? Indoors with a window, indoors with a grow light, outdoors in full/partial sun? If outdoors, what climate?

Comment: It's placed outside the west facing window and it receives direct sunlight during the afternoon. The climate is warm and humid here with temperatures ranging from 25 to 35°C.